# Having Overfull and underfull box warnings. Please help out as there are many matrices and equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}


The above equations on application of Laplace Transform become: 
$$sL_1\hat{i}_{L1}(s) = D\cdot \hat{v}_{C1}(s) + D\cdot \hat{v}_{C2}(s) - D\prime \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) + (C_{C1} + V_{C2} - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s)$$ $$sL_2\hat{i}_{L2}(s) = -D\prime \cdot \hat{v}_{C1}(s) + D\cdot \hat{v}+{C2}(s) + D\prime \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) + (C_{C1} + V_{C2} - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s)$$ $$sC_1\hat{v}_{C1}(s) = -D\cdot \hat{i}_{L1}(s)+ D\prime \cdot \hat{i}_{L2}(s) + (-I_{L1} -I_{L2} - I_1)\cdot \hat{d}(s) -D\prime \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)$$ $$sC_1\hat{v}_{C1}(s) = D\prime \cdot \hat{i}_{L1}(s)- D\cdot \hat{i}_{L2}(s) + (-I_{L1} -I_{L2} - I_1)\cdot \hat{d}(s) -D\prime \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)$$ $$sL_l\hat{i}_l(s) = D\prime \cdot \hat{c}_{C1}(s) + D\prime \cot \hat{v}_{C2}(s) - D\prime \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) +(V_g - V_D - V_{C1} - V_{C2})\cdot \hat{d}(s) - R_l \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)$$

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
181
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 181--181
181
Overfull \hbox (22.63293pt too wide) detected at line 181
```

Comment: Read from my lips: Don't use `$$...$$`

Comment: The posted example does not produce an underful box warning. I would guess your real document has `\\ ` on line 181, remove it.

Comment: For priming a symbol, use `D^{\prime}` or the shorthand `D'`; you can add as many apostrophes as you want, so `D''` is the same as `D^{\prime\prime}` and surely handier.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `$$` in LaTeX at all, (the LaTeX syntax is `\[`) but also don't use display math environments one after the other, use a mult-line display such as `align`.

Also use `'` not `\prime` to get a superscript prime.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


The above equations on application of Laplace Transform become: 
\begin{align*}
sL_1\hat{i}_{L1}(s) &=
\begin{aligned}[t]
 D\cdot \hat{v}_{C1}(s) + D\cdot \hat{v}_{C2}(s) - D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) + {}\\
(C_{C1} + V_{C2} - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s)
\end{aligned}\\
sL_2\hat{i}_{L2}(s) &= 
\begin{aligned}[t]
-D' \cdot \hat{v}_{C1}(s) + D\cdot \hat{v}+{C2}(s) + D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) + {}\\
(C_{C1} + V_{C2} - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s)
\end{aligned}\\
sC_1\hat{v}_{C1}(s) &= -D\cdot \hat{i}_{L1}(s)+ D' \cdot \hat{i}_{L2}(s) + (-I_{L1} -I_{L2} - I_1)\cdot \hat{d}(s) -D' \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)\\
sC_1\hat{v}_{C1}(s) &= D' \cdot \hat{i}_{L1}(s)- D\cdot \hat{i}_{L2}(s) + (-I_{L1} -I_{L2} - I_1)\cdot \hat{d}(s) -D' \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)\\
sL_l\hat{i}_l(s) &= 
\begin{aligned}[t]D' \cdot \hat{c}_{C1}(s) + D' \cot \hat{v}_{C2}(s) - D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) +{}\\
(V_g - V_D - V_{C1} - V_{C2})\cdot \hat{d}(s) - R_l \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

A possible variant, where all the equations are split in order to keep the width as small as possible; in order to better distinguish the various equations, some vertical space between them is added.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The above equations on application of Laplace Transform become
\begin{align*}
sL_1\hat{i}_{L1}(s) &=
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &D\cdot \hat{v}_{C1}(s) + D\cdot \hat{v}_{C2}(s) - D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) \\
    &\qquad + (C_{C1} + V_{C2} - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s)
  \end{aligned}
\\[1\jot]
sL_2\hat{i}_{L2}(s) &=
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &{-}D' \cdot \hat{v}_{C1}(s) + D\cdot \hat{v}+{C2}(s) + D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) \\
    &\qquad + (C_{C1} + V_{C2} - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s)
  \end{aligned}
\\[1\jot]
sC_1\hat{v}_{C1}(s) &=
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &{-}D\cdot \hat{i}_{L1}(s)+ D' \cdot \hat{i}_{L2}(s) \\
    &\qquad + (-I_{L1} -I_{L2} - I_1)\cdot \hat{d}(s) -D' \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)
  \end{aligned}
\\[1\jot]
sC_1\hat{v}_{C1}(s) &=
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &D' \cdot \hat{i}_{L1}(s)- D\cdot \hat{i}_{L2}(s) \\
    &\qquad + (-I_{L1} -I_{L2} - I_1)\cdot \hat{d}(s) -D' \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)
  \end{aligned}
\\[1\jot]
sL_l\hat{i}_l(s) &=
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
    &D' \cdot \hat{c}_{C1}(s) + D' \cot \hat{v}_{C2}(s) - D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) \\
    &\qquad  +(V_g - V_D - V_{C1} - V_{C2})\cdot \hat{d}(s) - R_l \cdot \hat{i}_l(s)
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also `\prime` is wrong!

Comment: @egreg oops will fix!

Comment: Thanks a lot. What should I be using instead of \prime?

Comment: @Reddy `'` I have updated the answer.

Comment: It says environment align* is invalid. Am I missing a package?

Comment: @Reddy Yes, see my answer which runs without error and produces the posted image, you need `amsmath`

Comment: Finally, all the mentioned small signal equations can  be summarized as,
\begin{align*}
sL\cdot \hat{i}_l(s) = (D-D')\cdot \hat{v}_C(s) + D'\cdot \hat{v}_g(s) + (2V_C - V_g + V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s) \\
sC\cdot \hat{v}_C(s) = (D' - D)\cdot \hat{i}_L(s) + (-2I_L + I_l)\cdot \hat{d}(s) - D' \cdot \hat{i}_l(s) \\
sL_l\cdot \hat{i}_L(s) = 2D' \cdot \hat{v}_C(s) - D' \cdot \hat{v}_g(s) + (-2V_C + V_g - V_D)\cdot \hat{d}(s) - R_l\cdot \hat{i}_l(s)
\end{align*}

Comment: How do I align the above piece properly?

Comment: Basically I need help with understanding this align environment

Comment: @Reddy the site doesn't really work if you ask new questions in comments. Your TeX distribution should show the documentation with `texdoc amsmath` and if you have further questions please just open a new question, where you can make a complete small document that demonstrates any issue you have.

Comment: @Reddy having said that, just ,mark alignment points before the `=` with `&` and put `\\ ` to mark end of each line.